# Easy way to create menus in GTK#?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

Is there an easy way to make menus in Gtk# ? In Gtk+ and PyGtk there is the ItemFactory which creates menus easily but it is bugged and deprecated in Gtk#, so is there any other easier way? Except for using a GUI Designer...

Comment: It's deprecated in GTK and PyGTK too.

Comment: @ptomato I know. I've used both. :D But it still works. It isn't bugged like in GTK#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`Gtk.UIManager`](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aGtk.UIManager).